# Calendar won't display JSON feeds

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

The following is from an error trap function in the JQUERY calendar event sources. The output will not display on the calendar, even if it is in a one line text file. I have tried several different date formats including UNIX timestamp. This is calendar 3.1.0. The same feeds work correctly in V 1.5.4.

The error event handler is being fired even though the response status is 200 and the response text is complete. JQUERY AJAX GET outside of the calendar function loads the data correctly. I can also retrieve the data via script and insert it into a event: [] block and it will display on the calendar. The data will also display properly when copied and pasted into an event block in the fullCalendar function.

```
[
  "readyState: 4",
  "getResponseHeader: function (a){var b;if(k){if(!h){h={};while(b=Bb.exec(g))h[b[1].toLowerCase()]=b[2]}b=h[a.toLowerCase()]}return null==b?null:b}",

  "getAllResponseHeaders: function (){return k?g:null}",

  "setRequestHeader: function (a,b){return null==k&&(a=w[a.toLowerCase()]=w[a.toLowerCase()]||a,v[a]=b),this}",

  "overrideMimeType: function (a){return null==k&&(o.mimeType=a),this}",
  "statusCode: function (a){var b;if(a)if(k)y.always(a[y.status]);else for(b in a)u[b]=[u[b],a[b]];return this}",

  "abort: function (a){var b=a||x;return e&&e.abort(b),A(0,b),this}",
  "state: function (){return d}",

  "always: function (){return f.done(arguments).fail(arguments),this}",
  "catch: function (a){return e.then(null,a)}",

  "pipe: function (){var a=arguments;return r.Deferred(function(b){r.each(c,function(c,d){var e=r.isFunction(a[d[4]])&&a[d[4]];f[d[1]](function(){var a=e&&e.apply(this,arguments);a&&r.isFunction(a.promise)?a.promise().progress(b.notify).done(b.resolve).fail(b.reject):b[d[0]+\"With\"](this,e?[a]:arguments)})}),a=null}).promise()}",

  "then: function (b,d,e){var f=0;function g(b,c,d,e){return function(){var h=this,i=arguments,j=function(){var a,j;if(!(b<f)){if(a=d.apply(h,i),a===c.promise())throw new TypeError(\"Thenable self-resolution\");j=a&&(\"object\"==typeof a||\"function\"==typeof a)&&a.then,r.isFunction(j)?e?j.call(a,g(f,c,M,e),g(f,c,N,e)):(f++,j.call(a,g(f,c,M,e),g(f,c,N,e),g(f,c,M,c.notifyWith))):(d!==M&&(h=void 0,i=[a]),(e||c.resolveWith)(h,i))}},k=e?j:function(){try{j()}catch(a){r.Deferred.exceptionHook&&r.Deferred.exceptionHook(a,k.stackTrace),b+1>=f&&(d!==N&&(h=void 0,i=[a]),c.rejectWith(h,i))}};b?k():(r.Deferred.getStackHook&&(k.stackTrace=r.Deferred.getStackHook()),a.setTimeout(k))}}return r.Deferred(function(a){c[0][3].add(g(0,a,r.isFunction(e)?e:M,a.notifyWith)),c[1][3].add(g(0,a,r.isFunction(b)?b:M)),c[2][3].add(g(0,a,r.isFunction(d)?d:N))}).promise()}",
  "promise: function (a){return null!=a?r.extend(a,e):e}",

  "progress: function (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){r.each(b,function(b,c){r.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&\"string\"!==r.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this}",

  "done: function (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){r.each(b,function(b,c){r.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&\"string\"!==r.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this}",

  "fail: function (){return f&&(c&&!b&&(h=f.length-1,g.push(c)),function d(b){r.each(b,function(b,c){r.isFunction(c)?a.unique&&j.has(c)||f.push(c):c&&c.length&&\"string\"!==r.type(c)&&d(c)})}(arguments),c&&!b&&i()),this}",

  **"responseText: [{'id':1,'title':'test','start':'2014-12-25T10:00:00','end':'2014-12-25T18:00:00','description':null}]",
  "status: 200",
  "statusText: OK"**
]
```

Comment: The code posted appears to be minified and also not formatted correctly. You will get more assistance if you post a more readable source and format it correctly.

Comment: It will help if you add to the post: A. Your calendar configuration and B. Your API or whatever you are calling the GET from.

Comment: Calendar configuration is just bare-bones basic, no added configuration other than the get call in event sources which was done to utilize the error handling function when event: 'eventSource' didn't work. The API is not the issue as it works with the previous

Comment: @Ziv- Calendar configuration is just basic, no added configuration other than the get call in event sources done to utilize the error handling function when event: 'eventSource' didn't work. The API is not the issue as it works with the previous version and the feed won't display even from a call to a text file with the JSON line being the only contents as this: [{'id':1,'title':'test','start':'2014-12-25T10:00:00','end':'2014-12-25T18:00:00','description':null}] - Different date formats were also tried to no avail. Sorry about the double post, it wouldn't let me edit past 5 minutes.

Comment: @Brian-  the posted code is the output from the JQuery error handler response headers which was fired even though as the last lines show, the JSON string was successfully returned with a status of 200. If the request is successfully returned, why an error?

Answer (score 0):

There's something screwy in your text formatting.

If you paste your sample data

```
'end':‌​'2014-12-25T10:00:00‌​'
```

into Notepad++ and use the "Encode in ANSI" option, it looks like this:

```
'end':â€Œâ€‹'2014-12-25T10:00:00â€Œâ€‹'
```

I first noticed because when I was just moving left/right with the cursor along the line, I had to press 3 times to get from 0 to ', and the column ID kept increasing while I did it.

Then when I ran fullCalendar with this data, the console error reported was

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

pointing to the line with the events on it, which also made me suspect a strange character.

If you remove these extra characters, and use that as the event source then fullCalendar works fine.

So...the solution is to fix whatever is generating the data incorrectly.

Comment: the code here was copied from a JS alert popup displaying the error. The data line does not have any extra characters in it when it is actually sent to the calendar. It doesn't display even if the data line is the only thing in a text file saved from Edit Pad Pro. It will work however if the line is pasted into the page itself in an event: block, so the encoding is not the issue, nor is the issue JQUERY being able to return the data, it is JQUERY in the calendar get call returning the error text that was pasted. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok then, I suggest you show us the code defining the calendar and the data source. The error you've posted in the original question really doesn't tell us much at all - it's just a load of internal jquery code. The only useful bit is the response text, where I picked up the encoding error. But if you're certain that's not the issue, and that it works when you hard-code the events into the page then it must be something else related to the setup or the data from the server. Create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve we can use which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: no I hope to have more time to post something on it over this weekend. There is really nothing special about the code, just using the example from the docs with even a pure text file of one line JSON data. As previously stated, all works with previous calendar version so I am at a loss as to why it is not displaying. If I do resolve I will post it here. Thanks for the follow-up.